# DataModel for Implementing row versioning in OLTP system

Tags: sql, database-design, normalization, data-modeling, scd

I have following table

- *Person(PID, Name, Dob, AddressId)* PID being surrogate key(auto incremented)
- *Address(AddressId, Line1, Line2, City, State)* AddressId being surrogate key(auto incremented)

PersonID (PID) is used in my lot of transaction tables. Since address of a person may change over the period of time, I need to store record version in database so that I can refer correct version according to time slice. How should I handle it.

I am thinking of having solution something like this

- Using same table to store history
  e.g.
- Person(PID, Name, Dob, AddressId)
- Address(AddressId, Line1, Line2, City, State, StartDate, EndDate,
  LastUpdatedBy, LastUpdatedDate)

Let's assume **initial** record of person as below

```
Person(100, X, Y, 110)
Address(110, A, B, C, D, 2011-01-01, 9999-12-31, Y, 2011-01-01)
```

Now address was changed in **2012** for PID 100. I am thinking to do

```
Address(320, A, B, C, D, 2011-01-01, 2012-06-01, Y, 2011-01-01) - INSERT
Address(110, A, B, Q, D, 2012-06-01, 9999-12-31, Z, 2012-06-01) - UPDATE
```

if address changes again in **2014** for PID 100. It would look like

```
Address(740, A, B, Q, D, 2012-06-01, 2014-06-01, Y, 2012-01-01) - INSERT
Address(320, A, B, C, D, 2011-01-01, 2012-06-01, Y, 2011-01-01) - NO CHANGE
Address(110, A, B, N, D, 2014-06-01, 9999-12-31, R, 2012-06-01) - UPDATE
```

Now I can query historical data as well as current data from same table without changing surrogate key. I won't have to refer historical tables hence no bombarding of logic and tables.

**This approach won't let me enforce unique key constraint on tables assuming I have Address Code being unique. How shall I handle this?**

Please suggest different approach and feedback on this.

Comment: Enforce a unique key on `AddressID` AND `StartDate`

Comment: The search term for this is "temporal tables". [Snodgrass's seminal book on temporal databases](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html) is free on his web site. The subject is more complex than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to make a relation table that contains dates:

```
Person_At_Address(PID,AddressId,StartDate,EndDate,LastUpdatedBy,LastUpdatedDate)
```

And remove the corresponding columns from Person and Address yielding:

```
Person(PID, Name, Dob)
Address(AddressId, Line1, Line2, City, State)
```

Now whenever a person changes the address you just insert a new row into the Person_At_Address table. When querying, you have got all the info you need about historic and current data.

As for your case with NO-CHANGE row, you have number of options to pull it out:

- You can have a scheduled job that inserts rows at given checkpoints in time if there is no row present for that time slice. Then select query gives you exactly the above output.
- You can also create a display like that after you run the query by filling in the missing rows in your application. That is fairly simple also.